# Ошибка DoesNotExist. Вылетает на user = User.objects.get(pk=u.pk)

Tags: mysql, django, orm

История: Вылетает ошибка на `user = User.objects.get(pk=u.pk)`, - `DoesNotExist`. Вообще не могу понять почему. Обработал эту строку исключением, теперь вообще не заходит в try. Где я ошибся и почему вылетает эта ошибка?

P.S. С базой данных все в порядке. В другом коде все работает. Данные я тоже проверил. Суть сего алгоритма в том, что он ищет заявки по двум городам, т.е. горд отправки и город прибытия. После этого он ищет **в заявке!** всех подписанных людей на нее. Потом я в userList["user"] добавляю объект. Потом делаю проверку: Если кол-во сидений (указывается в Ad) больше пользователей подписанных на эту заявку, значит в этой заявке есть свободные места и я эту заявку добавляю в список adList["name"]. И возвращаю пользователю. Все.

```
def searchAd(request, ad):
    j = json.loads(ad)
    a = Ad(**j)
    adList = {"name": []}
    userList = {"user":[]}

    if not Ad.objects.filter(cityStart=a.cityStart, cityEnd=a.cityEnd):
        return HttpResponse("null")

    for ad in Ad.objects.filter(cityStart=a.cityStart, cityEnd=a.cityEnd):
        for u in User.adPk.through.objects.filter(ad_id=ad.pk):
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(pk=u.pk)
                userList["user"].append(json.dumps({'name': user.name, 'serName': user.serName, 'email': user.email, 'password': user.password,'pk': user.pk}, ensure_ascii=False))
            except Exception:
                pass
        if ad.countSits >= userList["user"].__len__():
            adList["name"].append(json.dumps({'name': ad.name, 'timeStart': ad.timeStart, 'timeEnd': ad.timeEnd, 'cityStart': ad.cityStart,'cityEnd': ad.cityEnd, 'about': ad.about, 'driver': ad.driver, 'price': ad.price,'countSits': ad.countSits, 'pk': ad.pk}, ensure_ascii=False))

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(adList, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Comment: ну если ошибка в этой строчке, то посмотрите что в u.pk находится и проверьте наличие такого пользователя в базе

Comment: Запрос выполнен по двум городам на которые есть заявка с подписчиками. Я все внимательно проверил.

Comment: если работать должно, но не работает, то в подавляющем большинстве случаев проверяли недостаточно внимательно. Не смотрите по каким городам ищется, смотрите что сейчас у вас в u.pk находится. Потом проверяйте наличие записи с таким pk в таблице User. Если в pk что-то не то, значит тогда ищем проблему в другом месте. Но сейчас смотрим там, где ошибка, а не выше. У вас может подписчики есть, да записались криво и нет таких пользователей

Comment: Вы знаете, debug действительно показал мне, что я беру не совсем те значения из u.pk. Я буду долго объяснять почему в u.pk лежит не то значение которое мне нужно, но, спасибо вам что были рядом в эту трудные минуты моей жизни.

Comment: Используйте вместо `Exception` исключение `User.DoesNotExist`.